# Как создать реактивную форму, которая могла бы отправить 3 post-запроса?

Tags: javascript, angular

мой компонент с формой и методом, который подписан на один сервис

```
**private initTeamForm() {
    this.formTeam = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      position_id: this.fb.group({
        position_name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      }),
      file_id: this.fb.group({
        file: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      })
    });
  }
addTeam() {
    this.teamService.addNewTeam(this.formTeam.value)
      .subscribe(t => this.closeDialog(t));
  }**
```

как объединить в одном методе 3 сервиса и подписаться на них?

мои сервисы
team.service.ts

```
**addNewTeam(team: Team) {
    return this.http.post<Team>(this.apiUrl, team);
  }
```

position.service.ts

```
addNewPosition(position: Position) {
    return this.http.post<Position>(this.apiUrl, position);
  }
```

file.service.ts

```
addFileData(file) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrlFile, file , {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    });
  }**
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: По логике мне нужно одной формой создать один объект, в котором объединены 3 post запроса к разным моделям на сервере

Comment: Ну так и делайте три запроса, в чем проблема?

Comment: в самом методе addTeam я делаю subscribe на team.service.ts, т.е один запрос обрабатываю, а мне нужно сделать такой метод, который брал три сервиса с тремя запросами, объединял их вместе, где бы я мог сделать на них subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `forkJoin` из `rxjs` думаю справится с этой задачей:

```
addTeam() {
    forkJoin({
      newTeam: this.teamService.addNewTeam(this.formTeam.value),
      secondData: this.secondService.anyRequest(this.formTeam.value),
      thirdData: this.thirdService.anyRequest(this.formTeam.value)
    })
      .subscribe(response => this.closeDialog(response));
  }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробовать!